# Oracle preparedstatement

Tags: date, netbeans, oracle11g

I am trying to save this data into oracle datebase but (Member start Date and Member end date) giving an error i am using datepicker from JPallet for date and preparedstatemet allows me in pst.setString(6, startdate.getDate()); int or string. Please help me for solving this problem. I shall be very thankful to you.

Error Lines:

```
    pst.setString(6, startdate.getDate());
    pst.setString(7, enddate.getDate());
```

Full method:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    con = javadb.ConnectDb();

    try{
        String sql = "insert into membertable(id,name,membershipno,department,idno,"
                + "startdate,enddate,officeaddress,officephone,homeaddress,homephone,dateofbirth,"
                + "fieldofinterest,remarks) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = (OraclePreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, null);
        pst.setString(2, name.getText());
        pst.setString(3, membershipno.getText());
        pst.setString(4, department.getText());
        pst.setString(5, idno.getText());
        pst.setString(6, startdate.getDate());
        pst.setString(7, enddate.getDate());
        pst.setString(8, officeaddress.getText());
        pst.setString(9, officephone.getText());
        pst.setString(10, homeaddress.getText());
        pst.setString(11, homephone.getText());
        pst.setString(12, dateofbirth.getText());
        pst.setString(13, fieldofinterest.getText());
        pst.setString(14, remarks.getText());

        pst.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book added successfully!");

    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    update_table();

}
```

And date picker code is here

```
private void startdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

}
```

And this is not the textfield so therefore i am facing the problem. And i want to correct and also don't want to change it because it is front end reqiurement. Because user don't wants to insert date manually. Thanks.

Comment: You can't just do a `setString` if your DB field is a date.  There should be a similar `pst.setDate()` method you can use.

Comment: @Marc I am using pst.setDATE(7, enddate.getDate()); and this is also giving me error and my db field is date.

Comment: I am using JDatePicker and formate of that is Sun 12/22/2013 but don't know what is the format of oracle for storing date.

Comment: sorry but I do not understand what time is output of date picker, code is empty, can you please fix it, thx

Comment: private org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker jXDatePicker1;                                                                                                      private void jXDatePicker1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting a date, don't use `pst.setString()`. Instead, you should use `pst.setDate()` (this is really the whole point of using `PreparedStatements` in the first place). Because `setString` is inserting a date string with some unknown format. `setDate` tells the database to expect a date and there is no date format conversion necessary.

Also, to do this, you'll need to use a `java.sql.Date` instead of (what I'm assuming your palette is returning) a `java.util.Date`.

So this

```
pst.setString(6, startdate.getDate());
pst.setString(7, enddate.getDate());
```

should look like this

```
pst.setDate(6, new java.sql.Date(startdate.getDate().getTime()));
pst.setDate(7, new java.sql.Date(enddate.getDate().getTime()));
```

Comment: Man you are good... Actually Best! Thanks... Hats off! You are really a specialize in data-driven ERP solutions.

Comment: You should explore with the setters in the `PreparedStatement`. Like `setInt`, `setDate`, etc. Only use `setString` when you are inserting into a varchar/text field.